# How to Functors with no parameters and Functors with return-type void?

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have seen [this nice code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63841/c-function-composition). And want to use it for my case.

Therefor I changed the direction, so that `combine(f,g,h)(x)` means: do `h(g(f(x)))`.

But actually I want:

do `f(x)`.

If there is a result `y`, then do `g(y)`, otherwise do `g()`.

If there is a result `z`, then do `h(z)`, otherwise do `h()`.

So here is the changed code:

```
template<typename ... Fs>
struct combine_impl
{
    combine_impl(Fs&& ... fs) : functionTuple(std::forward<Fs>(fs) ...) {}
    static constexpr numberOfFs = sizeof ... (Fs);
    template<size_t N, typename ... Ts>
    auto apply(std::integral_constant<size_t, N>, Ts&& ... ts) const
    {
        return apply( std::integral_constant<size_t, N + 1>{}
                    , std::get<N>(functionTuple)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...));
    }

    template<typename ... Ts>
    auto apply(std::integral_constant<size_t, numberOfFs -1>, Ts&& ... ts) const
    {
        return std::get<numberOfFs -1>(functionTuple)(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

    template<typename ... Ts>
    auto operator()(Ts&& ... ts) const
    {
        return apply(std::integral_constant<size_t,0>{}, std::forward<Ts>(ts) ...);
    }

    std::tuple<Fs ...> functionTuple;
};

template<typename ... Fs>
auto combine(Fs&& ... fs)
{
    return combine_impl<Fs ...>(std::forward<Fs>(fs) ...);
}
```

Edit:
To make clear what the question was:
The example:

```
struct FunctorA
{
   float operator()(int k) const {return k*2.5f;}
};


struct FunctorB
{
   float operator()(float k) const {return k*2.5f;}
};

void main()
{
   float result = combine(FunctorA(),FunctorB())(4);
}
```

works fine with the code.
But I want to be able to also use code like this:

```
struct FunctorA
{
   voidoperator()(int k) const 
   {
       // side effects
   }
};


struct FunctorB
{
   float operator()() const 
   {
      return 42.f;
   }
};

void main()
{
   float result = combine(FunctorA(),FunctorB())(4);
}
```

This would not compile, because of `invalid use of void expression`.

Edit:
after some reading: this should be possible with sfinae. 
The expression

`decltype(std::get<N>(functionTuple)(std::forward<Ts>(std::declval<Ts>())...))`

is of type void when I need to use another version of apply.

Comment: Here is the code.... What is wrong with it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, put the question in the question and post an answer with the answer.

Comment: this will be solved by using sfinae. Still looking trying to figure out how.